# SSMS and Visual Studio run only with run as administrator

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ssms

I rebooted this morning and now my SSMS (v17.7) and Visual Studio Community 2017 (v15.7.4) run only if I start them with Run as Administrator.  If I simply try to open them, nothing happens - I get a wait cursor for a couple of seconds and the app never starts up.  I used to be able to simply open them.

I should add that I am currently logged in to an account with Admin privileges.

What happened?  Is there some setting that got clobbered that I need the change back?  Do I need to uninstall and reinstall them?